# React Select background color

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Any suggestions why this code is not setting background color for the Select?

I have a sample created at following location

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-basic-forked-3z0kd?file=/src/index.js

Comment: the prop is `styles` not `style`

Comment: I modified the above sample to use "styles" but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this outside your class:

```
// BACKGROUND STYLES

const customStyles = {
  control: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    background: "#023950",
    // match with the menu
    borderRadius: state.isFocused ? "3px 3px 0 0" : 3,
    // Overwrittes the different states of border
    borderColor: state.isFocused ? "yellow" : "green",
    // Removes weird border around container
    boxShadow: state.isFocused ? null : null,
    "&:hover": {
      // Overwrittes the different states of border
      borderColor: state.isFocused ? "red" : "blue"
    }
  }),
  menu: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    // override border radius to match the box
    borderRadius: 0,
    // kill the gap
    marginTop: 0
  }),
  menuList: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    // kill the white space on first and last option
    padding: 0
  })
};
```

And then implement it on your SELECT:

```
<Select
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={this.options}
          styles={customStyles}
        />
```

here is your code with background color working:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-basic-forked-5uyfb?file=/src/index.js

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you , this works. I am going to accept your answer.

Just a question: If I want to set the background color only when option 1 "Spring" is selected then how the this.options is going to be accessible in the Style?

Comment: im so sorry i dont know how to answer your question... try making another question post and hopefully people will help your problem

Comment: Sure will do, Thanks again.

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer i upvoted your post in return :)